# Configure RABC in K8S v 1.8.1

Tags: kubernetes

I am following [Configure RBAC](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/) to create user accounts, everything works fine, but after updating the context, before binding any roles with the created user, apiserver `kubectl get pods` returning the pods.

apiserver configuration

```
KUBE_API_ADDRESS="--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0"
KUBE_API_PORT="--insecure-port=8080"
KUBELET_PORT="--kubelet-port=10250"
KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES="--service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16"
KUBE_ADMISSION_CONTROL="--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota"
KUBE_API_ARGS="--client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt --tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.crt --tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key --authorization-mode=RBAC"
```

kubectl config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
    server: http://172.16.3.23:8080
  name: local
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: local
    namespace: kube-system
    user: devops
  name: devops
current-context: devops
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: devops
  user:
    client-certificate: /.cert/devops.crt
    client-key: /.cert/devops.key
```

p.s: I am using centos bare metal environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insecure port (http://...:8080) bypasses all authentication and authorization